# Apache commands failing with: AH00141: Could not initialize random number generator

Tags: apache2

Many Apache commands, such as `apache2 -v` and `apachectl graceful` are failing with this message:

`(38)Function not implemented: AH00141: Could not initialize random number generator`

Searches online have suggested this could be caused by Chinese characters in the `PATH`; I don't see any characters except `a-z` and slash. Others have suggested missing `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom`; both are present on my system.

If I run `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail`, I get numbers between about 130 and 250. Is this too low? Could this have something to do with it?

Other possibilities?

Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
Apache 2.4.46

Comment: Are you using Apache from a ppa?

Comment: I was using: ```http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/apache2/ubuntu```.
Removing that and downgrading to Apache 2.4.18 made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by downgrading `libapr1` from 1.7.0 to 1.5.2. To make it work, I had to downgrade `libaprutil1` (and two `libaprutil1-*`) from 1.6.1 to 1.5.4. I also had to stick with Apache 2.4.18.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this Debian bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=978045), it looks like Apache expects a kernel function to be there, that isn't necessarily there with every kernel:

> The issue is that if the library is configured (at build time) to
> USE_GETRANDOM, then it assumes that the getrandom() call will be available
> and
> if it fails it becomes a fatal error. On my system, I don't have getrandom()
> because I'm running an ancient kernel, but others could (more legitimately)
> have the option disabled on a recent custom-built kernel.

The best solution would probably be to update to a more recent version of Ubuntu. Ubuntu 16.04 is more than five years or ten release cycles old and will lose support in less than a month. Or as [the maintainer of the mentioned PPA put it](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/1567):

> With the experience of Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty EOL, I can't stress enough that you should plan ahead and have your servers already upgraded by now. Yesterday was too late.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 is supposed to have extended security support for several more years. It ought to keep working. Updating the entire OS is not a solution to the urgent need to get Apache up again.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to thank @Liam Morland for his answer above which led me to rectify this issue after an ill-advised apt-get update on Ubuntu 16.04. For those who might find it useful, here's exactly what I did:

1. Checked the log for apt-get to see exactly what software had been upgraded in the last round, and therefore what needed downgrading. `sudo tail /var/log/apt/history.log`
2. Searched through the data there to ascertain what varies of libapr1 and libutil1 I had installed. I ascertained that for me it was:

- libapr1
- libaprutil1
- libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3
- libaprutil1-ldap

Your system may vary!

3. Installed aptitude (`sudo apt-get install aptitude`). It is incredibly useful and gave me guidance on how to fix the dependencies, whereas apt-get gave me gibberish when I tried to downgrade.
4. Using the command `sudo aptitude versions libapr1` `sudo aptitude versions libaprutil1` I noted the exact version numbers that aptitude could supply. In my case, the version of libaprutil1 couldn't just be 1.5.4, it had to be 1.5.4-1build1.
5. Using the = sign to specify version, I ran `sudo aptitude install libapr1=1.5.2-3`. Aptitude then gave me a list of other software which would have been downgraded or stop working if I proceeded. I quit the install process, and using the error, crafted a single command to downgrade all the software that aptitude had identified. This was mine:

`sudo aptitude install libapr1=1.5.2-3 libaprutil1=1.5.4-1build1 libaprutil1-ldap=1.5.4-1build1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3=1.5.4-1build1 apache2=2.4.18-2ubuntu3.17 apache2-bin=2.4.18-2ubuntu3.17 apache2-data=2.4.18-2ubuntu3.17`

**This was based on my specific installation, so please check what you have before running this command.**

6. I gave Apache a restart and everything was working fine again!

I hope this helps anyone else on the road.

Answer (score 0):

is your machine running inside Solus / openvz?
then kernel from openvz is too old...
machines here had same prob under solus / openvz (kernel 2.6.xx)